# How ternary operators work in querying from a database in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Was wondering why it is not allowed to do this. This is under an import controller

```
if(!empty($insert)) {
    $insertData = DB::table('table_name')->insert($insert) 
        ? return back()->with('message', 'File contents successfully added') 
        : return back()->with('message', 'Error adding file contents');
}
```

Producing a `syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)` FatalThrowableError

However, it can do this:

```
if(!empty($insert)) {
    $insertData = DB::table('table_name')->insert($insert);

    if($insertData)
        return back()->with('message', 'File contents successfully added');
    else
        return back()->with('message', 'Error adding file contents');
 }
```

Comment: `return DB::table('table_name')->insert($insert) 
        ? back()->with('message', 'File contents successfully added') 
        : back()->with('message', 'Error adding file contents');`

Comment: same thing happens, @tkausl

Comment: You are attempting to set the value of `$insertData` to a return call ...

Comment: I really doubt my code produces the same error.

Comment: @Peter isn't that how ternary operations work? ($foo =  condition ? value if yes : value if no)

Comment: I don't think you can set the value of a variable to a return call. http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a return in your query, you are trying to set the value of `$insertData`.

here's an alternative way to shorten your code:

```
if(!empty($insert)) {
    $insertData = DB::table('table_name')->insert($insert);
    if($insertData) return back()->with('message', 'File contents successfully added'); 
    return back()->with('message', 'Error adding file contents');
}
```